# Can I get Entity Cache Tags from a Route?

Tags: 8, entities, routes, caching

If I have a node object I can use `$node->getCacheTags()` to get the cache tags for the node object, and I can do the same for other entities. Is there a way for me to do something similar with a Route object?

```
$cache_tags = $route->getCacheTags();
```

or maybe there's a way for me to do something like this, where $entity is populated with the $user, or $node, or $view, etc. object that is responsible for the current route:

```
$entity = $route->getEntity();
$cache_tags = $entity->getCacheTags();
```

Comment: It is not possible from the route itself. If you look at the [route class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor!symfony!routing!Route.php/class/Route/8.2.x) there is no getCacheTags() method. But you can get the entity from the route, see [Drupal 8: get entity object given system path?](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2014-07-25/drupal-8-get-entity-object-given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my eventual solution based on @No Sssweat's comment.

I created a method in a service like:

```
public function getEntityFromRoute(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
  foreach ($route_match->getParameters() as $param) {
    if ($param instanceof EntityInterface) {
      return $param;
    }
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

Then I have code like the following where I'm not entirely sure what entity type may be providing the route:

```
$route_entity = $MY_SERVICE->getEntityFromRoute(\Drupal::routeMatch());
$cache_tags = [];
if ($route_entity !== FALSE) {
  $cache_tags = $route_entity->getCacheTags();
}
```

Then I create my render array using the cache tags.